# BackgroundWorker, update gui, static method

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have app where I'm using background worker to start some sequence.
It needs to update GUI sometimes.

I have static class with references to some gui objects.
In my logic I want to call method from this static class, with some parameters, there analyse it and update GUI.
But I have "**The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.**" exception.

setting variable in first thread:

```
    public static void SetCardHand(ref CardHand ch)
    {
        cardHand = ch;
    }
```

Method called from background worker thread:

```
private static void SetCoveredCardsPlayer0(int cardsNumber)
    {

        if (cardsNumber < 1)
            cardHand.imgCard1.Source = null;
        else
            cardHand.imgCard1.Source = (ImageSource)WindowManager.Instance.CardsGUI.CardsDictionary["T1"];
    }
```

How to let this method change GUI?

## edit

It's not a window class. Its something like presenter.

## edit2

Its a card game. I'm starting it in background worker and I need to update Image source(representing card) after each Deal.

Comment: Depending on your app design the outline is backgroundworker.WorkerReportsProgress = true, and subscribe to ProgressChanged which will run on UI thread.

Comment: You have to detail *where* you're calling SetCoveredCardsPlayer0.  It should be either from the Completed or the ProgressChanged event handlers--if it isn't you'll get that exception.  See what Grant posted for an answer below if you make that call on something other than the Completed or ProgressChanged event handlers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to pass control back to the main thread prior to updating the UI. The BackgroundWorker makes this fairly easy.

1. When you create your `BackgroundWorker`, set `WorkerReportsProgress = true`.
2. Subscribe to the `ProgressChanged` event, and place your logic that updates the UI into that event.
3. Within your `DoWork` event, when you want to update the GUI, call `myBackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0, someObject)`, where "someObject" is the piece of data you want to act upon. In your case, probably the `ImageSource` you're assigning to `cardHand.imgCard1.Source`.
4. Inside the `ReportProgress` event, you can access the object your passing via `e.UserState`. You'll need to cast it back to an `ImageSource` before using it.

You can keep your `if (cardsNumber < 1)` logic inside the `DoWork` event, but when you want to set the `Source` to an `ImageSource` (or `null`), you'll want to pass that value to the `ProgressChanged` event to actually update the UI element.

Comment: Thats pretty fine, but I need few different types of updating.
How can it be done?